# Serial communication - node.js - no answer from arduino board

Tags: javascript, node.js, arduino

I try to use node.js to make communication between computer and arduino board. Simple program but it doesnt work.

Arduino program (work fine) :

```
void setup(){Serial.begin(9600);}
void loop(){
    Serial.println(1);
    delay(1000);
}
```

And node.js app:

```
var serialport = require("serialport");
    SerialPort = serialport.SerialPort;

var mySerial = new SerialPort("/dev/ttyUSB0", {
        baudrate: 9600,
        parser: serialport.parsers.readline("/n")
    });
mySerial.on("open", function(){
    console.log("Port OPEN.");
});
mySerial.on("data", function(data){
    console.log(data);
});
```

When i open app.js (*node app.js* in ubuntu terminal) i have "Port OPEN." and there is no received data. The port is good. When i try to do *cat /dev/ttyUSB0* in terminal i have "1" all the time. I try to send 1 as a string *Serial.println("1");* but it wont work too.
Where is the problem ? thx for help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try this and see if it works:

```
var SerialPort = require("serialport").SerialPort
var serialPort = new SerialPort("/dev/ttyUSB0", {
  baudrate: 57600
}, false); // this is the openImmediately flag [default is true]

serialPort.open(function (error) {
  if ( error ) {
    console.log('failed to open: '+error);
  } else {
    console.log('open');
    serialPort.on('data', function(data) {
      console.log('data received: ' + data);
    });
    serialPort.write("ls\n", function(err, results) {
      console.log('err ' + err);
      console.log('results ' + results);
    });
  }
});
```

Comment: Yes, thank you. It work good. I think the problem is with _parser: serialport.parsers.readline("/n")_